# Tikz figure doesn't display using the pdflatex command

Tags: pdftex, tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create an image file from Tikz content using the `pdflatex` command.

Here is the Tikz content:

```
\begin{document}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows, shapes}

\tikzset{
  box/.style    = {draw, rectangle, minimum height = 2.5em, minimum width = 2.5em},
  circl/.style  = {draw, circle, minimum size = 8mm,label={[font=\small, inner sep=1pt]200:$+$}},
  input/.style  = {coordinate},
  output/.style = {coordinate},
    to/.style    = {->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, semithick, font=\small}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I use the following command:

```
$ pdflatex figure.tex
```

The execution ends successfully but the pdf file is empty.

I'm using Linux Mint and installed Textlive:

```
ii  texlive                                      2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1                     all          TeX Live: A decent selection of the TeX Live packages
ii  texlive-base                                 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1                     all          TeX Live: Essential programs and files
ii  texlive-binaries                             2015.20160222.37495-1ubuntu0.1               amd64        Binaries for TeX Live
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended                    2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1                     all          TeX Live: Recommended fonts
ii  texlive-latex-base                           2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1                     all          TeX Live: LaTeX fundamental packages
ii  texlive-latex-recommended                    2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1                     all          TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
ii  texlive-pictures                             2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1                     all          TeX Live: Graphics, pictures, diagrams
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document is incomplete and can't be compiled successfully. At the very minimum, a documentclass is missing and the packages ought to be in the preamble, not in the document body:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows, shapes}

\tikzset{
  box/.style    = {draw, rectangle, minimum height = 2.5em, minimum width = 2.5em},
  circl/.style  = {draw, circle, minimum size = 8mm,label={[font=\small, inner sep=1pt]200:$+$}},
  input/.style  = {coordinate},
  output/.style = {coordinate},
    to/.style    = {->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, semithick, font=\small}
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! It works now and display something in the pdf. Is there a way to generate easily an image file instead of a pdf?

Comment: You could use `convert` from Image Magick to convert into whatever format you'd like. Or on mac, you could use `/usr/bin/sips -s format png "document".pdf --out "document".png` which plays a bit nicer with transparencies etc. (but note that if you convert this into a pixel based format, you'll loose all the advantages of a vector graphic)

Comment: Also have a look into the `standalone` documentclass, this can do the conversation automatically

Comment: So, not to loose vector graphic, is it possible to obtain a svg file at the end?

Comment: Compile with `latex document ; dvisvgm document.dvi` instead of pdflatex. As the name says, pdflatex is for pdf

Comment: Indeed! A small last question and I'll accept your answer. How can I adapt the size of the image to correspond to the size of the figure (with some padding around)? Thanks!

Comment: `standalone` documentclass

Comment: Okay but I got an error with it: `LaTeX Error: File standalone.cls not found.`. Is there something else to install?

Comment: Don't bother with these incomplete linux packages. Install a complete vanilla texlive from the TUG website and you'll have everything you'll ever need.

Comment: Saw what you mean but I will run latex on a server and I need to control the size of what is installed. I would like to have vanilla texlive with a scheme (or scheme with additional installation) that contains latex + tikz + standalone. Is it something possible? Perhaps the subject of another question on so? ;-)

Comment: Thanks very much!